# Looking for an algorithm that will show how to fit the most boxes in a container

Tags: algorithm, geometry, bin-packing

I've been interested in writing an application that will show how to fit boxes (of random dimensions) in a container so there is as little space as possible left.  A real life example would be something that would tell you how to use the most space in a UPS truck.  Does anyone know of a good place to start for something like this?  Is there an existing algorithm that does something similar to what I'm talking about?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140406/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-how-to-fit-smaller-boxes-into-a-larger-packa

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140406/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-how-to-fit-smaller-boxes-into-a-larger-packa

Comment: Reminds me of fitting chars into VRAM on GBA/GBC systems.  Same problem, difficult to solve well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of Tetris :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is a classic computer science problem known as bin packing, it is an NP-Hard defined problem with well known research and heuristics, but ultimately the only way of calculating it absolutely is via computation of every combination possible.

Read up on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem