# Build a Cube/Rectangular Prism with other Cubes/Prisms?

Tags: php, algorithm, math, geometry

I'm wondering, are there any algorithms or theories in existence (that aren't patented/proprietary/protected) that would take a series of 3d rectangular prisms (or cubes but a cube is a prism) and stacks them in such a way as they form another cube or fit together in the best possible format?

I'm working on logistics software at work and this might be an interesting feature.

I'd also accept good articles that discuss the theory of this, if an algorithm isn't already available for me to look at and study.

Comment: You might have better luck asking over at the Game Development portal, even though this isn't strictly a game development question.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: BY "form another cube or fit together in the best possible format", do you mean "stack the prisms such that the volume of the resulting bounding box is minimized"?

Comment: @mbeckish the idea is to find the optimal configuration for fitting prisms inside of another fixed prism so as to minimize gaps, or dead space. For instance stacking boxes on a pallet or pallets/boxes in a truck. Empty space is lost money in the logistics world. Granted my implementation would also have to account for stackability in addition to dimentions but that can be worked in once I understand some of the theory for the problem.

Comment: @DavidScherer - Sounds like there a lot of pertinent details missing from your post.  Like the "fixed prism" - that's an important constraint.  Also, the original post sounds like you have a set of input prisms, and they all have to be used to form some optimal resulting prism.  But your most recent comment sounds like you need to use some subset of the input prisms to optimally fit a given resulting prism shape.  Maybe you can add some more specifics to your post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically determine how to fit smaller boxes into a larger package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140406/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-how-to-fit-smaller-boxes-into-a-larger-pack)