# Algorithm for Box Selection / Space Optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, heuristics

So, I have an optimization/space management problem. This same question is posted on two SE sites simultaneously, Stack Overflow and Mathematics, since I think it is fitting for both.

Let's say I have containers of (X, Y) dimensions. Inside, I want to place as many smaller containers of (x_i, y_i) dimensions as possible. These smaller containers can vary in size. Inside these smaller containers, I have a given item which is the smallest unit I have.

Basically: Items, inside variable small boxes, inside variable big boxes.

Provided I know all of the following:

- Larger containers' dimensions.
- Smaller containers' dimensions.
- Amount of all containers available to me.
- Amount of basic items that need to be packaged.

Is there any known algorithm that can be applied to determine the following:

- The best selection of small boxes to be used (they can vary in size).
- The optimal number of large containers required for storage.
- The appropriate placement of the smaller packages inside the larger one.

IF this is a thing that already exists, can it be extended to three dimensions, rather than only two, as my example states? That is to say, calculate packaging configurations for dimensions (x, y, z).

**EXAMPLE:** I have

- 25 total items to pack
- 3 small containers with dimension: 3x3, 2x2, 1x2
- Dimension of the large container: 5x5

Through trial and error (or intuition?), I can see that a valid configuration is as follows:

- 1 small container of 3x3
- 3 small containers of 2x2
- 2 small containers of 1x2

All inside a single 5x5 container.

Now, it's a matter of *tetris*ing/*tangram*ing my way into a solution. So, for example, the following two are valid placements/configurations:

[image: Valid Configurations]

While this one isn't since it would require a second large container:

[image: Invalid Configuration]

Comment: So, you have infinite number of smaller boxes from each type?

Comment: I have a finite amount of items. I have, more often than not, more small boxes than would be required at that precise moment in stock; but not necessarily infinite. The same applies for the larger boxes. The issue here is mainly that this calculation should be performed continuously for different ammounts.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem to find that this is a variant on a well-known NP-hard problem, but many heuristics are known.  I'd start with that and decide how much work you're going to put in to producing as good a solution as you can.

Comment: Do the boxes have to be axis aligned?

Comment: That is not a constraint I am currently aware of

Comment: (Minding the age of the question...) You in fact stated the algorithm already: _trail and error_. You need to algorithmically come up with a way to explore the possible configurations, removing invalid ones and keeping ones that either could be valid or are a "successful" configuration. You're likely looking for a form of [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This is the well known [rectangle packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_packing) or [Korf's problem](http://contraintes.inria.fr/%7Etmartine/clp2zinc/clp2zinc-talk.pdf). [Here](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.8.0/en/MiniZinc%20Handbook.pdf) is a simple solution with MiniZinc with the restriction of not turning the rectangles. Other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140406/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-how-to-fit-smaller-boxes-into-a-larger-pack).

Comment: Note link-only answers are highly discouraged (and often removed as "not an answer"). It's better to include the essential parts of the answer in your post directly. Given the age of the question (2+ years), what are you adding to it now with this new answer?

Comment: @Rogue this questions was not answered and I had to deal with the same problem. I think short answers with links are usefull. The age of the question is not important here, Stack Exchange is a Q/A knowledge base.